# Intent to choose either a folder or a file

Tags: android, android-intent

I know how to build intents to open files with `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` or folders through

```
Intent fc = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
fc.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
```

Is there a way to build an intent to choose either a folder or, say, an audio file? If not, a folder or any kind of file?

I tried with `ACTION_PICK` without success.

Comment: There is no `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_OR_TREE` or any other single `Intent` that allows the user to select either a document or a tree at their discretion.

Comment: I see... What a pity. Thanks!